# $L^p$ norm of Fourier transform of function composed with a diffeomorphism

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose $f$ is a compactly supported smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ is a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n$, do we have any theorems relating the $L^p$ norm of $\hat{f}$ and the $L^q$ norm of $\widehat{f\circ A}$? Here hat denotes the Fourier transform. $p,q>1$,

Obviously for $A$ an invertible linear map this follows trivially from a change of variable. What about when $A$ is a more general nonlinear map?

Comment: What have you tried? One can start writing down some things using basic facts about the Fourier transform, but it would help to know where the basics are proving insufficient for your desired application.